# Validator textarea does not work and always returns false

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, textarea

I am trying to use kendo UI validator over a textarea using validateinput but always returns false. This Dojo contains the script.

Thanks for your help.

https://dojo.telerik.com/ifIhEGIy

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    function validateFormHecho() {
      var validator = $("#hechoForm").kendoValidator({
        rules: {
          controlValidate: function(input) {
            switch (input.attr('id')) {
              case 'txtDescripcion':
                return true;
                break;
            }
          }
        }

      }).data("kendoValidator");

      alert(validator.validateInput($("input[id=txtDescripcion]")));

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#txtDescripcion").kendoEditor({
        resizable: {
          content: true,
          toolbar: true
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>
<form id="hechoForm">
  <div><textarea rows="10" cols="30" id="txtDescripcion" name="txtDescripcion"></textarea></div>
  <button onclick="validateFormHecho()">Click me</button>

</form>

</html>
```

Comment: You could include that code in your post, it's not that long.

Answer (score 1):

you use `<textarea rows="10" cols="30" id="txtDescripcion" name="txtDescripcion"></textarea>`.
But in your alert you are searching for an input elem. Textarea is not a classic HTML input, so you have to edit this part:

```
alert(validator.validateInput($("input[id=txtDescripcion]")));
```

to

```
alert(validator.validateInput($("textarea[id=txtDescripcion]")));
```

Or use `$("#txtDescripcion")` as the id selector

PS: you misspelled txtDescrip **t** ion ;)

Answer (score 0):

There simple is not `input` element with that id. If you search for any element with that id, you get your `true`: `alert(validator.validateInput($("#txtDescripcion")));`